# JMSMEssage ID is all zero's

Tags: jms

When I drop a message in a MQ, JMSMessage id is getting generated as

`000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

When I tried to drop another message, I get the same id.

My questions here are:

1. In what case does MQ generate this id?
2. Won't it be duplicate one?

Comment: Hi, after quite a time I have faced this issue again. I could see JMS message id as all zero's after dropping the message in queue...any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

The JMS message ID is generated after the message is sent to MQ. That is after MessageProducer.send() is invoked. I think you are reading the value of JMS message Id value before the send call.

There won't be a duplicate message and the message ID is generated while the message is placed on the queue.

Comment: Hi Neeraj,
I am reading the value after putting the message in queue. After dropping the message in queue, I am printing the object where I can see JMSMessage ID is all zero's and JMSCorrelationID: null (I am not receiving any reply for this)
Any other cause why I am getting it so..

Comment: Any other options find out why it is all zero's?

Comment: hi, anyone could help me on this?